# System.ArgumentNullException: "Значение не может быть неопределенным. Имя параметра: value"

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При компиляции выдает ошибку: "Исключение не обработано"

```
string HWID;

private void Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HWID = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value; 
}

WebClient wb = new WebClient();
            string HWIDLIST = wb.DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/domi4n/hwidforskeet/main/hwid.txt");
            if (HWIDLIST.Contains(HWID))
            {
                string mainpath = "C:\\Windows\\random.dll";
                wb.DownloadFile("https://example.ru/example.dll", mainpath);
                var name = "csgo";
                var target = Process.GetProcessesByName(name).FirstOrDefault();
                var path = mainpath;
                var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HWID Error");
            }[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Comment: У вас `HWID` имеет значение `null`.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Читайте прилинкованный ответ, отлаживайте код. Научитесь писать код самостоятельно, а не копировать чужой, чтобы не попадать в ситуацию "всё пропало, [код из интернета](https://github.com/WilsonPublic/SimpleLoader/blob/master/GitHub%20SimpleLoader/Form1.cs) не работает".

Comment: Что касается проблемы, если это Winforms, убедитесь, что в дизайнере формы вы подключили обработчик события `Form.Load`. Очень похоже на то, что метод `Load` не выполняется вообще. К сожалению, непонятно ни что за тип приложения у вас, не то, как устроен ваш код за пределами показанного участка. К сожалению, вы дали ровно столько информации, чтобы вообще ничего непонятно было.